# Labeling top 10% values in ggplot loop R

Tags: r, ggplot2

**UPDATE**
I narrowed the problem down to the loop i. because if I just use a specific column ("b") in the code below, it works. Does anyone know what is wrong with i and why the loop wont work?

I have a large dataset where I loop over multiple columns to create graphs. I want to label the top 10% dots in the graph for i(and later on the lowest 10%). I've tried a lot but cannot figure out how to label only the top hits. The label names should correspond to column "label"

in the example I tried it with gghighlight, which does not work.

```r
## loading packages
library("ggplot2")
library("purrr")
library("ggbeeswarm")
library("gghighlight")

## creating data
group <- c("Control", "PAD", "Control", "PAD", "PAD", "Control", "PAD", "Control", "PAD", "PAD", "Control", "PAD", "Control", "PAD", "PAD")
label <- (1:15)
b <- round(runif(15, 1, 7))
c <- round(runif(15, 1, 3))
d <- round(runif(15, 3, 8))
e <- round(runif(15, 1, 5))
event <- c("no event", "event", "no event", "no event", "no event", "no event", "event", "no event", "no event", "no event", "no event", "no event", "no event", "event", "event")

df <- data.frame(group, label, b, c, d, e, event)
df

rm(group, label, b, c, d, e, event)

# add color coding to the dataset
df$color <- "color"
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  if (df$group[i] == "Control") {
    df$color[i] <- "Control"
  }
}
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD with event"
  }
}
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "no event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD without event"
  }
}

rm(i)
## this is where i am having issues
for (i in names(df)[1:4]){
ggplot(df, aes_string("group", "b")) + 
  geom_boxplot(show.legend = F) + 
  geom_beeswarm(aes(color = color), size=2) +
  scale_color_manual(values= c("Control"="#107f40", "PAD with event" = "#D85622", "PAD without event"="#2D416D")) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(b>quantile(b, 0.9, type=2, na.rm = TRUE), as.numeric(label),'')))

}
```

I don't get an error but it labels all the values instead of only the top hits. Additionally, the labels are not set to "label" column but to group instead.
please find an example below an example of how I would like to see the labels (only on the top hits)
[image: example]

Comment: 1) variables `expl` and `response` are not used in your code. 2) You don't load `library(ggbeeswarm)` and `library(gghighlight)`. 3) Inside the loop, `g <- ggplot(...etc...)` and then `print(g)` does label the points, just not the way you want them labelled. Could you please revise your code an see what's the problem now?

Comment: adjusted. I do get labels, but they are the wrong labels. I want the "label" column as label instead of the "group". Additionally I only want the top hits to be labeled

Comment: You have a typo in gghighlight: `lable` should be `label`

Comment: you are right. the code did not contain that error though. problem still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pdf("labels_test.pdf", width = 15)
for(i in 1:42) {
print(ggplot(df2, aes(x = event, y = value, color = color)) + 
  geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values= c("PAD with event" = "#D85622", "PAD without event"="#2D416D")) +
  geom_point(data = df2 %>% filter(flag), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df2 %>% filter(flag) %>% unique(), 
                   aes(label = Study_no),
                   color = "black") +
  facet_wrap_paginate(~ key, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, page = i))
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following does what the question asks for.
It first reformats the data and then plots all box-and-whiskers plots in facets.
The main point is to use `ggrepel::geom_label_repel` to have the labels positioned away from the points.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

df2 <- df %>%
  select(-event) %>%
  gather(key, value, -group, -label, -color) %>%
  group_by(group, key) %>%
  mutate(flag = value >= quantile(value, 0.9, type = 2))

g <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = group, y = value, color = color)) + 
  geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values= c("Control"="#107f40", "PAD with event" = "#D85622", "PAD without event"="#2D416D")) +
  geom_point(data = df2 %>% filter(flag), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df2 %>% filter(flag) %>% unique(), 
             aes(label = label),
             color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ key)

g
```

[image]

## Data creation code.

I repost the code in the question to make it reproducible by setting the RNG seed.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

group <- c("Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD", "Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD", "Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD")
label <- 1:15
b <- round(runif(15, 1, 7)) 
c <- round(runif(15, 1, 3)) 
d <- round(runif(15, 3, 8)) 
e <- round(runif(15, 1, 5))
event <- c("no event", "event" , "no event" , "no event" , "no event", "no event", "event", "no event", "no event" , "no event" , "no event" , "no event", "no event", "event", "event")

df <- data.frame(group, label, b,c,d, e, event)
df

rm(group, label, b, c, d, e, event)

df$color <- "color"
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$group[i]=="Control") {
    df$color[i] <- "Control" 
  }
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD with event" 
  }
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "no event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD without event"
  }
}
```

Comment: This partially solved the issue. There is actually one issue left and that is the following: I have to loop over 190+ columns. Is there a way to loop over them and save the plots on multiple pages? With this code I can only loop the columns but it adds them in 1 grid? 190 graphs in 1 grid would of course be unreadable

Comment: @JensPosma There is a function `ggforce::facet_grid_paginate` and another `ggforce::n_pages` to determine the number of pages needed. Try them and if you have any problems, post a comment.